# SEO friendly Search Result implementation

Tags: sxa, seo

I would like knowing if anyone has implemented Search Result page with other filters in SXA supporting "Querystring" (serverside) instead of "Hash" (AJAX) to achieve SEO. OOTB SXA search component returns the response through AJAX, what if google crawls your search or listing page.

Comment: We were thinking about moving from hash parameters to query string in the past. But this would basically mean to rewrite whole search logic and we give up.
We are using backbone.js (that is pretty old logic, it was written in times when beckbone.js was quite popular) in most of the search scripts. Backbone by default is using a hash to store params. There are some articles showing that it is possible to switch to query string but just at the beginning we already found a couple of issues with this.

Comment: Because SEO companies keep asking this request and we are in same situation that it will require complete rewrite of the logic.

Comment: I've implemented a SEO friendly version of a SXA listing page using the search components. What I actually did was creating a custom component that uses the `scope` defined in SXA to do the search, as well as the pagination from SXA. The output is done with variants so we are reusing lots of SXA stuff. It's a bit much to show all code here. The pagination part can be found on https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/12/sxa-pagination-on-custom-component.html. The reuse of the scope will be done in the near future..

Comment: Believe me - you don't want to do that...

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a SEO friendly version of a SXA listing page using the search components. What I actually did was creating a custom component that uses the `scope` defined in SXA to do the search, as well as the pagination from SXA. The output is done with variants so we are reusing lots of SXA stuff.

It's a bit much to show all code here, but lets try to give you the highlights. The pagination part can be found on https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/12/sxa-pagination-on-custom-component.html. The reuse of the scope will be done in the near future..

**Pagination**

For pagination on a custom component:

- Your rendering does need rendering parameters. The rendering parameters temlate for your component should inherit `IPaginable` and `IPagination` (both from the `Feature/Experience Accelerator/Page Content/Rendering Parameters` folder
- The rendering item needs `IsPaginationEnabledRendering` true as (other) property
- Your controller needs to derive from `PaginableController`.
- Implement the function `PaginationConfiguration` in the controller to generate a `IListPagination`. This is the object you can pass to the repository that fetches the data to select the required page.
- Implement the function `OnActionExecuting` in the controller to initialize the pagination context `ListPaginationContext`

**Scope**

To reuse the scope, note that a scope is actually a rendering parameter. You can read it - will be a string with the guid in it.
To get a query based on the scope:

```
var scopeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(scope));
var scopeQuery = scopeItem[Constants.ScopeQuery];
var model = SearchStringModel.ParseDatasourceString(scopeQuery);

using (var context = searchContextBuilder.GetSearchContext(indexName))
{
  var query = LinqHelper.CreateQuery<ContentPage>(context, model);
```

Comment: Converted to a comment as this falls under a link only answer.